# Reset password in a P2P native app using only username

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, authentication, native

I'm about to develop a **P2P** native chat app for android using react native. I would like to log in my user by asking for a username and a password. In case the user forgets his password is there any way to reset it without create the user from the start and losing all the data stored in device like chats or contacts?

Comment: yes, there is. Have you ever been to a site with a link "forgot your password"? do what they do

Comment: i.e. when a user clicks on "forgot password", one method is to send a link to the registered email address that allows a user to create a new password - you create a specifically crafted link so that when the user opens that link **you** know that it's the link from the email **you** sent, and you allow the user to change the password

Comment: Yes I understand this but what about the case that I don't use an email at all? I am only asking for a username and a password.

Comment: well, that's difficult I guess